# Как найти самый большой и самый маленький элемент массива

Tags: javascript

если правильно понимаю сначала надо сравнить все элементы и найти больше меньше?

```
let x = [4,3,1]
function solution(x){
    let min
    let max
    for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[0]>x[i]){
            max=x[0]
            console.log(max])//не пойму ка двигаться дальше
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: вставь в вопросе код текстом а не картинкой

Comment: Я так понимаю это задание "для тренировки", почему бы тогда не сравнивать каждый элемент с `min` и `max`? Если текущий элемент меньше, чем `min` - присваиваем к `min` значение элемента. Если текущий элемент больше, чем `max`, то присваиваем к `max` значение элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let x = [5, 4, 3, 6]
let min = x[0], max = x[0]
for(let i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
  if(x[i] < min)
    min = x[i]
  if(x[i] > max)
    max = x[i]
}
console.log("Минимальное значение: ", min, "\nМаксимальное значение: ", max)
```